# Wordpress and file uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-hosting

I realise there is going to be loads of answers to this question.. But anyway I have a Wordpress website that is hosted with 1and1 and purpose of the website is for users to upload photos and videos to the website. But I keep getting internal 500 errors when users try to submit anything larger than 1.5mb.

I've checked with 1and1 and I have the best package and should be able to handle uploads of more than 120mb with unlimited storage. Is there a better host I could use that's designed for what I need or can I change anything in the PHP files?

its running on the latest version Wordpress and PHP. Any recommendations would be great :)

Comment: Because according to 1and1 im out using my PHP runtime. Which is why it works with smaller files but not with larger ones

Comment: You have to take a look into your php.ini file. There are some options to modify the max file upload size.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with the execution time try including the following at the top of your PHP script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 200);
```

That will allow your script to upload for 200 seconds. To set this value site wide, look into modifying your php.ini file.

You could also try:

```
set_time_limit(200);
```